# Javascript arguments weird structure

Tags: javascript

For some reason, this has eluded me for a long time, but why do some api documentation list their arguments as such:

```
peripheral.discoverServices(serviceUUIDs[, callback(error, services)]);
```

(https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble)

the arguments seem to be an array but not? What's the reasoning behind writing down an argument like this?

Comment: Means callback is optional. It's a notational thing for documenting the API.

Comment: FWIW, this convention comes from unix man pages for documenting unix commands. For example, `ls` is documented as: `ls [OPTIONS]... [ARGUMENTS]...`